# Algorithm design, implement an algorithm for a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I found this interesting question related to algorithm design, i wasn't able to solve it properly.

> Given a directed graph G = (V,E), which uses  adjancency lists, and an integer k < |V|, implement a linear-time-complexity algorithm ( O(n) ) ,  to check if the graph G has at least k vertexes with the same indegree number.
>   Suppose n == |V| + |E|

Comment: Is it safe to assume `undegree` supposed to be `indegree`? I've never heard of `undegree`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for correction. I'm correcting now. As you can see english is not my native language.

Comment: Your English seems fine to me. I was only unsure about that one word, which was probably just a typo :)

Comment: Is `n == |V| + |E|`?

Comment: Is not specified, sir.

Comment: But when i tried to resolve it, I supposed, logically, n == |V| + |E|

Comment: I sent an e-mail to my University Professor, who was surpirsingly wake up at 2 a.m. (Italy timezone)
He confirms n == |V| + |E|

Comment: Have you tried breadth or depth first traversal? Can you access the inward edges of a node, or can you only access outward edges?

Comment: I tried both, but i wasn't able to solve the problem at all. If i understood properly your second question: there isn't specified any kind of constraint to edges' access. Do you have some ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Gerald, on SO you should post some code or at least explain what you tried and why it didn't work. It will incite people to help you more easily. Besides, you will avoid flags because your question can sound like : "could you do my homework, please?" So: show what you tried ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to pass through all edges, or even through all edge in-nodes, and maintain number of vertices for all possible indegrees.

Sketch of method in pyhon style:

```
def check(graph, k):
  # For each vertex count indegree
  indegrees = [0] * graph.number_of_nodes()
  # 'Maps' number of vertices to indegree
  num_with_indegree = [graph.number_of_nodes()] + [0] * (graph.number_of_nodes()-2)
  # Pass through all edge innodes.
  # This iteration is easy to implement with adjancency list graph implementation.
  for in_node in graph.in_nodes():
    # Increase indegree for a node
    indegrees[in_node] += 1
    # 'Move' vertex to it's indegree bucket
    indegree = indegrees[in_node]
    num_with_indegree[indegree-1] -= 1
    num_with_indegree[indegree] += 1
  # Returns true if any bucket has at least k vertices
  return any(n >= k for n in num_with_indegree)
```